# rails 4 ajax edit form not firing update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to update comments on a post in place, and I can get the edit form partial to render correctly, but trying to save does nothing--there's no console error, no error in the server logs, and the record isn't saved.

edit.js.erb

```
$('#comment-<%= @post.id %>-<%= @comment.id %>').find('.comment-content').html("<%= j render partial: 'comments/comment_form', locals: { comment: comment, post: post } %>");
```

comments/_comment_form.html.erb

```
<div class="comment-form col-sm-11">
          <%= form_for([post, comment], :remote => true) do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_area :content, class: "comment_content", id: "comment_content_#{post.id}" %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>
      <% end %>
</div>
```

update.js.erb

```
$('comment-form').hide();
$('#comment-<%= @post.id %>-<%= @comment.id %>').find('.comment-content').html('<%= @comment.content %>');
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
end

resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Below is the last thing in the server log when the edit_post_comment_path link is clicked; literally nothing happens when save is clicked in the edit form partial, and a test alert in update.js.erb doesn't fire.

```
Started GET "/posts/471/comments/30/edit" for 72.231.138.82 at 2016-07-17 01:25:27 +0000
Processing by CommentsController#edit as JS
  Parameters: {"post_id"=>"471", "id"=>"30"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  RailsSettings::SettingObject Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "settings".* FROM "settings" WHERE "settings"."target_id" = ? AND "settings"."target_type" = ?  [["target_id", 2], ["target_type", "User"]]
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 471]]
  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."user_id" = ? AND "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 2], ["id", 30]]
  Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 30]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered comments/_comment_form.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered comments/edit.js.erb (13.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 102ms (Views: 34.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

I have similar create, destroy and custom actions (including an update_attributes method) that are firing correctly, so I'm not sure why this form can't submit.  Any help is appreciated, I'm very new to js.

Update with the comment controller actions:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post
  before_action :user_signed_in?, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :edit, :new, :destroy, :update]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  ...

  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'comments/edit', locals: {comment: @comment, post: @post } }
    end
  end

  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
    if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
      @comment.toggle!(:edited)
      flash[:success] = "Comment edited!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :user_id, :post_id)
  end

  def set_post  
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end 

  def correct_user
    @comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @comment.nil?
    redirect_to root_url if @comment.userlocked?
  end

end
```

I've updated the edit form with :method => :put, to no effect, and thanks for the typo catch @Emu.

Comment: can you post your comment controller

Comment: you must have to `render js` in your controller

Comment: @Marv-C, just added it.  @uzaif, could you explain a little more how/where in the comments controller `render js` would be added?  This is my first time trying to render a form with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're submitting an edit form, you should define the **method** in the `form` like:

```
<%= form_for([post,comment ], :remote=>true, :method => :put) do |f| %>
```

Also, in the `update.js.erb` the following line missing the `"." or "#"`

```
$('.comment-form').hide();
```